# ElasticSearch и спецсимволы

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Всем привет. Никак не могу понять, как в Elastic искать слова со спецсимволами

Например, у меня есть два документа:

1) We are looking for C++ and C# developers 
2) We are looking for C developers

Я хочу найти только документ, в котором есть слово С++.

Код создания индекса, документов и поиска:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import scan

ELASTIC_SEARCH_NODES = ['http://localhost:9200']

INDEX = 'my_index'
DOC_TYPE = 'material'


def create_index():
    data = {
       "settings": {
          "analysis": {
             "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                   "type": "custom",
                   "filter": [
                      "lowercase"
                   ],
                   "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }

    print es_client.indices.create(index=INDEX, body=data)


def create_doc(body):

    if es_client.exists(INDEX, DOC_TYPE, body['docid']):
        es_client.delete(INDEX, DOC_TYPE, body['docid'])

    print es_client.create(index=INDEX, doc_type=DOC_TYPE, body=body, id=body['docid'])


def find_doc(value):
     results_generator = scan(es_client,
            query={"query": {

                    "match_phrase" : {
                        "text" : value
                    }

            }},
            index=INDEX
        )
     return results_generator


if __name__ == '__main__':
    es_client = Elasticsearch(ELASTIC_SEARCH_NODES, verify_certs=True)

    # create_index()
    doc1 = {"docid": 1, 'text': u"We are looking for C developers"}
    doc2 = {"docid": 2, 'text': u"We are looking for C++ and C# developers"}

    # create_doc(doc1)
    # create_doc(doc2)

    for r in find_doc("C++"):
        print r
```

Результат поиска (если [экранировать](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters) `+`, то результат тот же):

```
{u'_score': 0.0, u'_type': u'material', u'_id': u'2', u'_source': {u'text': u'We are looking for C++ and C# developers', u'docid': 2}, u'_index': u'my_index'}
{u'_score': 0.0, u'_type': u'material', u'_id': u'1', u'_source': {u'text': u'We are looking for C developers', u'docid': 1}, u'_index': u'my_index'}
```

Насколько я понял, такой результат получается потому, что при разбиении на токены символы вроде `+` и `#` [не индексируются](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178550/elasticsearch-return-the-tokens-of-a-field), и на самом деле он ищет документы, в которых есть символ `C`:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/material/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : { }
    },
    "script_fields": {
        "terms" : {
            "script": "doc[field].values",
            "params": {
                "field": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Результат выполнения команды:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "my_index",
      "_type" : "material",
      "_id" : "2",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "terms" : [ "and", "are", "c", "developers", "for", "looking", "we" ]
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "my_index",
      "_type" : "material",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "terms" : [ "are", "c", "developers", "for", "looking", "we" ]
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Как можно решить эту проблему? И второй вопрос, связанный с предыдущим: можно ли осуществлять поиск только по небуквенным символам: `%` или тот же `+`?

P.S. Использую Elastic 2.3.2 и библиотеку для Python elasticsearch=2.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все спецсимволы индексируются, экранировать ничего не надо. В вашем случае, скорее всего, при индексации был использован стандартный анализатор, а не ваш my_analyzer.

Вам необходимо добавить маппинг.

```
data = {
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase"
               ],
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
       "material": {
           "properties": {
               "docid": {
                   "type": "integer"
               },
               "text": {
                   "type": "string",
                   "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Индекс придется пересоздать заново и снова добавить документы. При поиске также следует использовать my_analyzer или приводить слово к нижнему регистру. "C++" и "c++" - это разные токены.

Проверить на какие токены будет разбита строка анализатором my_analyzer можно следующим запросом:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&pretty=true" -d 'We are looking for C++ and C# developers'
```

Поиск можно осуществлять по любым символам ("%", "+").